# How do I update a BehaviorSubject within a flatMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have `BehaviorSubject` declared as `Object`.

I know how can I update it within a `subscribe` with `next()` but how can I update it after a `flatMap()`?

The `BehaviourSubject`:

```
user = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});
```

The method that set user data and user details data (after user data).

```
this.userDetailsService.getUserDetails()
.flatMap((res) => {
    //update this.user details in res??
    return this.getUser();
}
).subscribe(
    data => {this.user.next(data)}
);
```

The user object looks like this:

```
{

    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test"

}
```

After calling `userDetailsService`, the user should get more details like:

```
{

    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test",
    "details1": "other",
    "details2": "other"

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem with `this.user.next(data)`. It's called after `flatMap`. Maybe you're looking for `do(user => this.user.next(user))`.

Comment: I have updated the question with the model details

Comment: I actually still don't understand where's the problem. You want to keep in `BehaviorSubject` first the original object and then replace it with the "enhanced" object?

Comment: Maybe I am thinking wrong. I want to get the user basic information (the subscribe), after I finish the subscribe, I will get the userDetails. After I get all the information I want to update the BehaviorSubject. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Without more info on `this.userDetailsService.getUserDetails` I'd assume that this is what you want:

```
this.user = this.userDetailsService.getUserDetails()
    .flatMap((res) => {
        return this.getUser();
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my question with userDetailsService. Only after the subscribe I will get more data from userDetailsService.

Answer (score 0):

BehaviorSubject returns to the new subscriber the last emitted Object, when you are already subscribed then you will be only notified, when next is called.

Possible solution:

```
user: User;

this.userDetailsService.getUserDetails()
.switchMap((details) => updateDetails(details))
.subscribe(user => {this.user = user)});

updateDetails(details): Observable<User> {
  return this.getUser().do((user) => user.setDetails(details));
}

getUser(): Observable<User> {
 return Observable.of(this.user);
}
```